Blazor isn't using my component for redirecting unauthorized users
I'm trying to implement authorization in a .NET 8 Blazor server-side app. When a user isn't logged in and tries to access a page that requires authorization, I want to redirect to the login page. I did the same thing the default Blazor Web App template with "Individual Accounts" does but used a different URI. But my URI is ignored and the redirect goes to /Account/Login. Am I misinterpreting what <NotAuthorized> does?
Here's Routes.razor:
@using DataCollection.UI.Components.Shared
<Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
            <NotAuthorized>
                <RedirectToLogin />
            </NotAuthorized>
        </AuthorizeRouteView>
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
</Router>

Here's RedirectToLogin.razor (defined in DataCollection.UI.Components.Shared):
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"ui/Login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}", forceLoad: true);
    }
}


In my test you might select the Interactive location as "per component", the "global" mode will not get this problem. The solution is simple too.
App.razor
...
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BlazorApp25.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="RenderModeForPage" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    private IComponentRenderMode? RenderModeForPage => HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/Account")
        ? null
        : InteractiveServer;
}

The document has the explanation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-8.0
